# Read ini file C++ error

Tags: c++, ini

I have an ini file that has this info:
and this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "IniReader.h"
#include "INIReader.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    INIReader reader("C:\SampleFile.ini");

    if (reader.ParseError() < 0) {
   cout << "Can't load 'test.ini'\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Config loaded from 'test.ini': version="
              << reader.GetInteger("info", "CaptureDuration", -1) << "CaptureDuration"<<"\n"
              << reader.Get("info", "DayStart", `enter code here`"UNKNOWN") << ", email="; 


cin.get();
 return 0;   
}
```

I also attached the INIReader header file that I found from this link:
https://code.google.com/p/inih/source/browse/trunk/cpp/INIReader.h
I want the code to print the integer and the string values that it got from the ini file. but I am getting Linker errors. How can I fix it?

```
Errors:
,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?Get@INIReader@@QAE?AV?$

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall INIReader::ParseError(void)" (?ParseError@INIReader@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main

1>C:\Users\Owner1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\inireader\Debug\inireader.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I do't see any lib file to link to this project, where should I get the lib files?

Comment: Use angle brackets `<...>` for those `#include` statements.

Comment: It is stunningly difficult to get rid of file formats that mattered 25 years ago.  Reading an INI file is enormously expensive, between 20 and 50 milliseconds for a single setting.  Let's all blame a C++ compiler to think that `\S` is a valid character, very hard to get rid of as well.

Comment: @HansPassant : 20ms is about average seek + latency on any reasonable HDD.  - or are you saying that the Windows API is slow? But, what's a better choice if performance and ease of manual tweaking is important? (If you say XML or registry, I will probably laugh...)

Answer (score 1):

**LNK2019** typically has one of the following reasons:

- You forgot to link the proper lib file for your library (the ini reader in this case).
- You linked the wrong lib file for your library (e.g. static vs. dynamic linking).
- You forgot to add a cpp file for your library to your project.
- You're mixing precompiled code that's meant for different platforms (like x86 and x64).

Edit:
In this particular instance, you'll have to add the file **IniReader.cpp** to your project, as it provides the missing functions.

Comment: Thanks. But where can I find the lib files. Usually I find them in debug and attach them to the project but I don't see them here.

Comment: I want to use CaptureDuration=GetPrivateProfileInt("info", "CaptureDuration", 143, "C:\SampleFile.ini"); but it print the defaullt number here not the numbers inside the ini file. Wht can I do?

Comment: You'll have to add **IniReader.cpp** to your project.

Comment: @user2748701, One way is adding .cpp to your project. If your do not want to include the source code in your project, you shall add the class IniReader to an empty project and compile the project to get the dll and libs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows API like `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString` for reading .ini files. It works fine and does not require any libraries. I used it for decades.

Comment: Good luck trying that on another platform though. :) But yeah, for some Windows only program, they'd be the best way to go I guess.

Comment: Initial post contains `stdafx.h`... This looks to be a Windows project.

Comment: I used GetPrivateProfileString but it prints the number I wrote inside the function not the one in the file.It print 1057 and 143!
    using namespace std;
             int main(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
    {
      char DayStart[1000];
      int CaptureDuration;
      GetPrivateProfileString("info", "DayStart","1057",DayStart, 255,"C:\SampleFile.ini");
      
      CaptureDuration=GetPrivateProfileInt("info", "CaptureDuration", 143, "C:\SampleFile.ini");
      // N.B. WritePrivateProfileInt() does not exist
     cout<<DayStart<<CaptureDuration;
       cin.get();
     return 0;

Comment: I do not see the problem in your code. It should work. Check returned data in the debugger. Your problem "it prints the number" is something unrelated to these APIs. APIs are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

- Copy all files of `inih` into your project directory *(I think it is C:\Users\Owner1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\inireader)*
- Drag all files of `inih` into your project in *Visual Studio 2008*.
- Then press *build* button.

The error's reason is like @Mario said. You just compiled your cpp file, but not compile other cpp files that is necessory for your project. So you also need to compile all .cpp files in `inih`.

Note: I think you should read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html) to learn more about the compiling and linking of C.